# Add a click event to list items in a tree of lists

Tags: jquery, tree, onclick, click, html-lists

I have a tree of lists in Html such as this:

```
<ul class="myTree">
    <li class="treeItem">Category 1
        <ul>
            <li class="treeItem">Subcategory 1 1</li>
            <li class="treeItem">Subcategory 1 2
                <ul>
                    <li class="plus"><input type="text" value="Add a product"/></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="treeItem">Category 2
        <ul>
            <li class="treeItem">Subcategory 1 1</li>
            <li class="treeItem">Subcategory 1 2
                <ul>
                    <li class="plus"><input type="text" value="Add a product"/></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

So as you can see, it's a kinda elaborated list.

Now what I need is a click event on those "treeItem" class elements that would retrieve the corresponding name (Category 1, Subcategory 1 1, etc).

I came up with this:

```
$(".myTree").on("click", ".treeItem", function() {
    var categoryName = $(this).text();
    alert(categoryName);
});
```

The only problem I'm facing right now is that first of all, `categoryName` contains

```
Category 2

                Subcategory 1 1
                Subcategory 1 2
```

when I click on a "level 1" `<li>` (such as Category 1). I could bypass this by adding some `catname` attribute to my `<li>`'s but most importantly, when I click on a "level 2" `<li>` (such as Subcategory 1 1), it first triggers click event on level 2 `<li>`, does the stuff and then fires a new click event on level 1 `<li>`...

It's quite obvious why it does that, but I need a way around to have it only happen once in the highest level (when I click on "Subcategory 1 1", it should NOT fire an event on "Category 1").

It's also worth noting that this tree will be generated automatically, which means I could label my `treeItem`'s with some other class such as "level1" or something like that but if I could avoid that, I'd love it.

... Alright this question might need a summary as I felt I kinda lost myself in it...

1. I need a click event on a tree of lists
2. I need that click event to only be fired at the highest level (the deepest).
3. Adding some class names is possible but would like to be avoided.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all you need to use `event.stopPropagation` to stop the event bubbling up the DOM and repeating itself. Then you need to get the first text node within the `li`. Try this:

```
$(".myTree").on("click", ".treeItem", function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    var categoryName = $(this).contents().filter(function() {
        return !!$.trim(this.innerHTML||this.data);
    }).first().text();
    alert(categoryName);
});
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/53Eg7/)

Comment: Thank you :) I don't really understand your filter but it works so I'm gonna say it's fine this way :P. Thx for your help!

Comment: No problem. The `contents` returns all the elements withing a given element including text nodes. The `filter` is removing the leading/trailing whitespace, and then it simply returns the first element, which in your case is the text node containing the `Category x` string. It looks more complicated than it is ;)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `event.stopPropagation()` on the event.

```
$(".myTree").on("click", ".treeItem", function(event) {
    var categoryName = $(this).text();
    alert(categoryName);
    event.stopPropagation()
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your help :) Unfortunately Rory McCrossan was quicker and more complete. Thanks anyway!